# Common config for both Firebase and Google Cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

For a project, I am trying to deploy Google Cloud functions as well as Firebase Cloud functions from the same file. That is, I have initiated a Firebase project and in that project file I'm trying to deploy a Google Cloud function for the same project.

The problem I'm facing is that the config for G Cloud function is to be hardcoded in the code itself because unlike Firebase Cloud functions, it is unable to get it from functions.config(). Is there a way in which we can get the config for both the platforms using a single method? Or an alternative way so that for G Cloud functions we don't have to hard code the config again and again?
an example of what hard coded config means is as follows.
For establishing connection to mysql-

```
function getMySQLConfig() {
  if (!mysqlConfig) {
    // const config = functions.config();
    //const connectionName =  config.config_server_sql.connectionName;//

    mysqlConfig = {
      // config we get from functions.config()       

      // host: config.config_server_sql.ip,
      // port: config.config_server_sql.port,
      // user: config.config_server_sql.dbUser,
      // password: config.config_server_sql.password,
      // database: config.config_server_sql.dbName,
      // multipleStatements: true,
      // charset: "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",

      //hard coded config
      dbName: "config_db",
      ip: ‘IP_ADDRESS,
      dbUser: "root",
      port: 3306,
      connectionName: ‘SAMPLE_NAME’,
      password: ‘PASSWORD’,
      ...configSetting
    };

    // mysqlConfig.socketPath = `/cloudsql/${connectionName}`;    
  }

  return mysqlConfig;
}
```

Comment: They are the same thing. Can you share your code snippets and show what "config" you are referring to by "hardcoding"? Also, if it's a background function like Firestore trigger it might be easier to deploy via Firebase

Comment: @Dharmaraj , when deploying the g cloud function , it takes all config. files to be undefined , thats why had to hard code it.

Comment: [Secrets manager](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/secrets#console) might be useful for you. You can add all envs in there and the access the same in both using same code.